# Java applet fails to run, Application Error, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, applet, classnotfoundexception

A Java applet I have been trying to load has failed to run. The box supposed to show the application reads: Error. Click for details.

The Application Error is ClassNotFoundException

applets.twodeeeditor.mathEditor

Details are as follows:

```
Java Plug-in 10.75.2.13
Using JRE version 1.7.0_75-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\dell
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

Clicking "Reload" yields "Internal Error: java.lang.NullPointerException, in unproctoredTest.QuestionSheet"

I have enabled java applets under internet options, and "allowed" the site in question under the java control panel, but the applet still does not work.

Any help would be appreciated, as I am not familiar with the Java code terms.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 3) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Answer (score 0):

We had a ClassNotFoundException after using java 8 update 45. I'm trying to discover what happens.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u45-relnotes-2494160.html